# How to generate new html code in python each time page is loaded?

Tags: python, html, apache

I have some code in python that creates a .html file by joining some strings and values from a list. However, I'd like this to be as dynamic as possible, and have it recreate the html code as you open the web page. Google tells me, cgi is what I want (doesn't sound quite like it is, but it's the closest I could find).

However, as many things as I found that says cgi is what I want, nothing told me how to get it working, and if it did tell me, then it was far too complicated for me to comprehend.

The web server I want it to run on is apache2.

Comment: Google for *wsgi python*. It is a funny thing. Do you have PHP experience?

Comment: I don't, I only know python and enough html to get things to show on a page